# Finding groups with minimum mean deviation

Tags: algorithms, standard-deviation, dynamic-programming, means

Is there any algorithm that groups consecutive elements in an array that gives the minimum mean deviation. 
For example we are given an array a=[1,2,3,4,8,2,3,5]

There can be many "consecutive" groups or clusters like (1+2),(3+4+8),(2+3+5) whose mean comes out to be (3+15+10)/3=28/3=9(approx). and deviation comes out to be (9-3)^2+(9-15)^2+(10-15)^2/3.

How to find which grouping has the minimum mean deviation?

Comment: Interesting problem. I think it would probably have to be a heuristic algorithm or rely on some property of the mean function (e.g. linearity, monotonicity with increasing valued data point) since the number of possible partitions of a set (not multiset) grows very quickly. See: [Bell's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set).

Comment: Additionally you may want to specify that the whole set is not a valid choice since then the variance (as calculated by the population variance) is a minimum, being $0$. It's the same for the choice of each element on its own.